# canonicalize a path name on solaris

Tags: bash, path, solaris, symlink

On a GNU system I would just use `readlink -f $SOME_PATH`, but Solaris doesn't have readlink.

I'd prefer something that works well in bash, but other programs are ok if needed.

**Edit:** The best I've come up with so far uses cd and pwd, but requires some more hackery to deal with files and not just directories.

```
cd -P "$*"
REAL_PATH=`pwd`
```

Comment: Why not just download and build the GNU coreutils package, and use the readlink from that? I've do that on both SunOS and Darwin and it worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does [this](http://publicobject.com/2006/06/canonical-path-of-file-in-bash.html) help? From the referenced page:

Create a file called `canonicalize` with these contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$1")" &&
printf '%s\n' "$(pwd -P)/$(basename -- "$1")"
```

Make the file executable:

```
chmod +x canonicalize`
```

And finally:

```
user@host$ canonicalize ./bash_profile
```

Comment: You really ought to state the actual solution.  We can't even guarantee that wikipedia.org will stick around forever, let alone 'publicobject.com'

Comment: I've added an excerpt from the referenced page.

Comment: `basename -- $1` and `dirname -- $1` assumes gnu versions, solaris versions will not deal well with `--`.

Comment: canonicalizing is not just getting the absolute path, you also need to follow symlinks

Answer (score 6):

Might be overkill, but this is OS portable, and does not need to find the dirname nor basename binaries first..  this one-liner works.  Just pass in your filename where you see $origFile:

perl -e "use Cwd realpath; print realpath(\"$origFile\");"

Comment: This works great for the usual situation; unfortunately, `Cwd::realpath` is quite a bit slower in Solaris as compared to Linux (perl 5.10 on both)

Comment: It is not OS portable to Windows, as realpath will output Windows paths with forward slashes instead of backslashes.  This is undesirable in many cases.

Comment: In the case where you want the other kind of slashes on Windows, you can use a Perl regular expression right there to switch it, with a conditional for doing that on Windows.  Perl makes that easy enough, and it can still be a one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Resolves a full path
# - alternative to "readlink -f", which is not available on solaris
canonicalpath() {
  if [ -d $1 ]; then
    pushd $1 > /dev/null 2>&1
    echo $PWD
  elif [ -f $1 ]; then
    pushd $(dirname $1) > /dev/null 2>&1
    echo $PWD/$(basename $1)
  else
    echo "Invalid path $1"
  fi
  popd > /dev/null 2>&1
}
```