# Is "/lib64" different from "/lib/../lib64/"?

Tags: python, bash, gdb

In the gdb python script /opt/gcc-4.8.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.18-gdb.py the following line is present

```
libdir = '/opt/gcc-4.8.2/lib/../lib64'
```

instead it could have been **/opt/gcc-4.8.2/lib64**. Does this make any difference in bash or python?

Answer (score 1):

Paths often look like this when constructed by shell scripts that don't want to depend on being on Linux. It's harder to canonicalize pathnames (get rid of the ..) on other platforms. [Like Solaris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245301/canonicalize-a-path-name-on-solaris).

It's not a problem to leave the paths like they are.